# How to subscribe for raw notifications for specific topic in windows phone 8.1 universal app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I found a lot of code examples on how to register for raw notifications. But I can't find how to restrict to a specific Topic. Have I missed something?

That's my code so far:

```
var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

var taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
var trigger = new PushNotificationTrigger();
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);
taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = SampleTaskEntryPoint;
taskBuilder.Name = SampleTaskName;
taskBuilder.Register();
```

Answer (score 1):

see this channel 9 video for the details of windows-phone-8.1 notification. it is in quite details. push notification part starts from 24:25

[Tiles, Notifications, and Action Center](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/14)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this video, but unfortunately there is no information about raw notifications and no information about topics.

Comment: follow this blog form Mike Taulty. it show how you can register raw notification with background task also show the background task progress in forground app(if app is running).
http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/04/04/windows-phone-8-1-trying-out-push-notifications.aspx

hope this will help